# Is there a way to handle getaddrinfo() output with a single loop and IPv6 socket?

Tags: c, linux, networking, posix

I would like to be able to loop through a list which is a result of the `getaddrinfo()` function and call `connect()` using every element of that list until `connect()` is successful. Unfortunately, even when I specify the `AI_ALL | AI_V4MAPPED` flags, and an `AF_INET6` family, the results are mixed. The first part of the list contains `sockaddr_in6` structures, and the second part `sockaddr_in` structures, so i can't use them with an `AF_INET6` socket.

I know i can create two sockets. I would like to know whether it's possible to do it with just the `AF_INET6` socket.

Here's the operating system:

```
> uname -a
> Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 12 03:40:32 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Why can't you just skip the v4 addresses?

Comment: @Erik: maybe because some hosts do not support ipv6...

Comment: @Adrien: I understood OP as wanting only ip6... Perhaps not.

Comment: I'm learning the API, and I want to write a reliable client that will be able to connect to a server that is using either type of socket.

Comment: @kubi: `AI_ALL | AI_V4MAPPED` with `AF_INET6` is supposed to return all found IP4 mapped to IP6 - sure you're not getting IP4 addresses both as IP6 and IP4? If you do, you can still skip `AF_INET` addresses

Comment: No, I'm actually trying to connect using every result, and none are successful. I also have another version that connects using an `AF_INET` socket just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry if it's an AF_INET or AF_INET6 socket you are creating.
Simply pass the data from the getaddrinfo() call to the socket() call.

e.g.

```
/* returns -1 on error, or a connected socket descriptor*/
int opensock(const char *hostname, const char *service)
{
    struct addrinfo hint, *host, *res = NULL;
    int tcp_sd = -1, error;

    memset(&hint, '\0', sizeof(hint));
    hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    error = getaddrinfo(hostname, service, &hint, &res);
    if(error){
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG,"getaddrinfo failed. Cant find host %s: %m",hostname);
        return tcp_sd;
    }
    for (host = res; host; host = host->ai_next) {
        tcp_sd = socket(host->ai_family, host->ai_socktype, host->ai_protocol);
        if (tcp_sd < 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(tcp_sd, host->ai_addr, host->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
            close(tcp_sd);
            tcp_sd = -1;
            continue;
        }

        break;      /* okay we got one */
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return tcp_sd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I wanted to know was the canonical way to do it. Do you happen to know if calling socket() many times in a pessimistic scenario may lead to a performance loss, since it requires some work to be done by the kernel?

Comment: It will hurt performance. You could just remember whether the socket family was the same as in the previous loop iteration though and avoid closing and reopening it in that case.